# Entity Framework dbcontext adding an association to model when the database cannot be changed

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hyperlink, entity-framework-5

I am fairly new to EF and my experience so far has been to use the model as is. so,  I have an existing database that I have created a model for in EF 5.  it has no relationship defined in the database.  I cannot change the database itself, but I want to define that relationship in my model to avoid having to do inner linq queries or joins.  by setting this up in the model, do I risk this to persist to the actual database?

Comment: Are you concerned with possibility of creating new foreign keys in database due to defining new relationships in entity framework designer? This willn't happen. You have to  use explicitly  Entity Framework Wizard tools to generate new database.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Entity Framework 6.0 Code First Approach with Existing database?

You might find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj200620.aspx) helpful!